# ¿Cómo leer un texto o frase larga en c++?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Si defino un Char[i] (según conozco se limita el tamaño de la frase a i), pero yo no conozco el tamaño del texto a introducir. Además en el problema pedía el uso de la librería iostream solamente.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char txt[1024];
    cout<<"Ingrese la frase "<<endl;
    cin.getline(txt,1024);
    cout<<txt;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: qué has intentado hasta ahora? puedes definir el char después, hasta que sepas que va a llegar.

Comment: De momento no poseo idea alguna :c

Comment: Se puede usar memoria dinámica. Pero te aconsejo la clase string

Answer (score 1):

Cuando escribes `char txt[1024]`, no estás limitando el tamaño de nada. Solamente te reservas espacio para 1024 caracteres. Lo que limita el tamaño de la frase leída es `cin.getline(txt,1024);`.

Técnicamente podrías escribir más de 1024 caracteres en ese array, pero escribirías en una zona de memoria no reservada y fuera de control. Y el resultado es inesperado.

De hecho, al imprimirlo con `cout<<txt` recorres el array posición a posición hasta encontrar el caracter nulo `\0`. Si nadie te ha escrito encima, sobrevives, pero es peligroso.

Usar arrays de caracteres para cadenas de texto es muy eficiente, pero necesitas sabes el tamaño máximo que vas a necesitar a priori para evitar corrupciones de memoria. Si lo desconoces, desde la propia http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/ te dicen de usar `std::string` para leer archivos.

```
std::string txt;
std::getline (std::cin, txt);
```

Aunque si solo puedes usar `<iostream>`, no se me ocurre ninguna solución segura.
Si descubres cómo, compártelo :D